# Python send/recv on same socket multiple threads

Tags: sockets

I have one socket and two threads, thread 1 ONLY writes to socket, thread 2 ONLY reads from socket. No other threads interact with the socket.

Is there an issue with this implementation? I have read that python sockets are not threadsafe, but does that matter in this scenario?

Comment: The main issue you're likely to face is when it comes time to shut down the network connection (e.g. because your program no longer wants to use that connection, or because you want to exit cleanly).  Since both threads are using the socket, you'll need to get both threads to exit before you can safely `close()` the socket, and that can be dfificult to do if either of the threads are blocked in calls to `send()` or `recv()`.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the response. I am still fairly new to sockets so please correct me if I am misunderstanding anything.


1. Send will not block unless the send buffer is full correct?


2. Is the issue you mentioned applicable to any socket that is blocking? Or only to my scenario?


3. Is the best solution to use non-blocking sockets and select?

Comment: Send will block if it can't copy at least one of the bytes from your buffer into the kernel's outgoing-data-buffer.  (Note that for a TCP connection that condition can happen quite easily if you are sending a non-trivial amount of data and there is any packet loss due to congestion or whatever).  Order-of-operations-on-shutdown issues apply to any object that is being concurrently accessed by multiple threads, including sockets (blocking or not) and other things too.  Non-blocking sockets and select help a lot, since a thread blocking in select() can be more easily awakened and told to exit.